# Google play InAppProduct API get returns 400

Tags: google-play, google-play-developer-api

I'm doing a server-side validation of the purchase made via the android app. For this, I need to make 2 calls

1. [purchases.subscriptions.get](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions/get)
2. [inappproducts.get](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/inappproducts/get)

The 1st call to the purchase subscription API is successful whereas the 2nd call to the in-app products API fails. It was working fine until yesterday and started failing all of a sudden

Can someone please let me know what the next steps are? I found [this](https://groups.google.com/g/google-apis-explorer-users/c/sJ5glcRva_s) thread which talks about the exact same issue but it's almost 7-8 years old and I see no conclusion on it. Looks like this could be a bug on the Google's end but I'm not sure

Any help is greatly appreciated

Here's the error I'm getting from the API

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Non-existent in-app product",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Non-existent in-app product",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of last Google Billing Library update in May.

You might be using this API in your backend for fetching some product details, so be careful — after making the subscription editable you will receive errors like the one you received from that API if you try to fetch converted subscription info. The same will happen to all new subscriptions created after May, 11th.

More details here: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/compatibility#managing_subscription_status